# How to wait for request to finish before execute the next operation (Xcode 11)

Tags: request, wait, xcode11, swift5, operation

I have a code that allows fetching data on firebase. I need to wait until the request has been satisfied to execute the next operation.

I have tried something like this:

```
var a = [String : Any]()
let group = DispatchGroup()
group.enter()

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    dbRef.child("results/users").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if let res = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
            a = res
        }
    }
}

group.notify(queue: .main) {
    print(a)
}
```

But it does not work: I expected that this displays the value of a. (The code used to retrieve data from firebase works.) Instead, nothing is displayed.

Does somebody have an idea? 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it with this:

```
var a: [String:Any]

func myFunction(completion:@escaping (Bool) -> () ) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        dbRef.child("results/users").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if let res = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
            a = res
        }
    }
}


myFunction { (status) in
    if status {
        print(a!)
    }
}
```